# Do I need resistors for Dot-Matrix LED with driver IC?

Tags: dot-matrix-display

I bought a small dot-matrix board and now I am asking myself whether I need resistors for each LED or if the driver (a MAX7219EWG) supplies the correct voltage for the LEDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf) the IC can regulate the current through the LEDs by using a single resistor on the Iset pin.

So you don't need resistors for each of the LEDs but you do have to take care to select one.

[image]

[image]